# How to configure PyCharm for automatic code completion without ^space?

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

When typing in PyCharm, I used to automatically get code-completion suggestions without having to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

I must have accidentally (not sure how) changed my configuration to disable this, because now I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see the suggestion list.

Before, when trying to import randrange from random, I would type:

```py
from ra
```

and would automatically get a list of options including `ra`.

Answer (score 3):

In <kbd>Settings</kbd> ▶ <kbd>Editor</kbd> ▶ <kbd>Code Completion</kbd> check <kbd>☑ Autopopup code completion</kbd>.

Here's a screenshot from IDEA with what I'm pretty sure are the defaults for that whole thing. PyCharm should be about the same.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Sorry for the trivial question, but this was annoying me to no end.  Everything works the way I like it now.  Haven't got enough reputation to upvote yet, but greatly appreciate the answer.